# Physical Interpretation of Interference Terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, feynman-diagrams

Consider the following process:
$$e^- + e^+ \rightarrow \mu^- + \mu^+,$$
it contains 2 Feynman diagrams. One with the photon propagator and the other with the $Z$ propagator. The square of the scattering amplitude $|\mathcal{M}|^2$ can be expand to:
$$|\mathcal{M}|^2=|\mathcal{M}_{photon}|^2+\mathcal{M}^*_{photon}\mathcal{M}_Z+\mathcal{M}_{photon}\mathcal{M}^*_Z+|\mathcal{M}_Z|^2$$
$|\mathcal{M}_{photon}|^2$ is the pure electromanetic interaction and $|\mathcal{M}_Z|^2$ is the pure weak interaction, but what does the interference term $\mathcal{M}^*_{photon}\mathcal{M}_Z+\mathcal{M}_{photon}\mathcal{M}^*_Z$ do? What's its physical interpretation? And what effect does it cause?

Comment: Do? Can you write down the electron coupling to the Z and observe that, (due to a bizarre coincidence!) it is almost *pure axial*? (Of course the coupling to the γ is strictly pure vector.) Can you work out the implications on angular distributions? What happens near the Z mass? Btw, "pure weak" might well confuse some...

Comment: Basically, the γ–Z interference determines the energy dependence of the forward-backward asymmetries and dominates them at off-Z-peak energies, cf [PDG](http://pdg.lbl.gov/2016/mobile/reviews/pdf/rpp2016-rev-standard-model-m.pdf): (10.5a,b), (10.31c), (10.35). But you must reshape your question to indicate what of these standard reviews you fail to appreciate.

Comment: So why does the $\gamma - Z$ interference has little contribution to the total differential cross section but has an obvious effect on the asymmetry?

Comment: Perhaps you should focus your question, as already invited. The asymmetry goes like *F2* , (10.36),  which does affect the x-section, (10.31a,c). Note it vanishes for vanishing axials, which I already emphasized is the linchpin to the Z-coupling at tree level.  The pure-Z amp wins at the pole, but the interference is, ipso facto, less suppressed off it. Read up on Hollik, ref 149.